# Javascript : RemoveEventListener with Anonym Function

Tags: javascript, events, anonymous-function

How to remove and event listener with an `Anonym` function , with `removeEventListener()`;

```
document.getElementById("object").onclick = function(e){
    if(e && e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
          e = window.event;
          e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

So I have this piece of code and the function what's called must be anonym I'dont know why but If it's not then doesn't works correctly, maybe beacuse of the event :|

But If it's anonym how can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you havent added an actual event listener, you have just populated the onclick variable with a function to be run. So you should be able to just use something like this:

```
document.getElementById("object").onclick = false;
```

**EDIT**

Just tried it in jsFiddle and what I suggested works.

Answer (score 2):

Just give it a null value, which is the starting value when onclick is not initialized:
 `document.getElementById("object").onclick = null`